# Read value of non-blocking update in current simulation time

Tags: verilog

When writing testcases for synchronous register updates in Verilog, I would like to verify the values assigned to those registers in the current time step. For example (although `$display` is used in this example, I would like to be able to substitute it with any code that evaluates `counter`):

```
reg clk = 'b0;
always #10 clk = !clk;

reg [7:0] counter = 0;
always @(posedge clk) counter <= counter + 1;

initial begin
    $monitor("monitor %0t, %0d", $time, counter);

    @(posedge clk);
    $display("display %0t, %0d", $time, counter);

    @(posedge clk);
    $display("display %0t, %0d", $time, counter);

    $finish;
end
```

Simulating this code will print

```
monitor 0, 0
display 10, 0
monitor 10, 1
display 30, 1
monitor 30, 2
```

So, at any particular time step, `$display` sees a different value of `counter` than `$monitor`. Importantly, the value seen by `$display` is the *previous* value of the register. This makes writing testcases difficult.

The reason for this behavior is that evaluation events (e.g., the evaluation of `counter` inside `display`) are executed before non-blocking assignment events (e.g., the update of `counter`) and `$monitor` events are executed after that ([IEEE Standard Verilog® HardwareDescription Language](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/fa06/Labs/verilog-ieee.pdf), Chapter 5)

I came up with the following work-around:

```
reg non_blocking_reg = 'b0;
always @(posedge clk) non_blocking_reg <= !non_blocking_reg;
reg updates_done;
always @* #0 updates_done = non_blocking_reg;
```

What this code does is the following:

1. `non_blocking_reg` is a register that gets synchronously updated on every clock cycle;
2. `updates_done` is a register that is procedurally assigned to `non_blocking_reg`. This causes an update of `non_blocking_reg` to schedule an update event for `updates_done`. The explicit zero delay (`#0`) ensures that this update event is scheduled in the inactive event queue and thus executed after all non-blocking assignment events;
3. Therefore, waiting for change events of `updates_done` waits until *all* synchronous register updates are executed.

Using this work-around, my original code can be written as follows:

```
initial begin
    $monitor("monitor %0t, %0d", $time, counter);
    @(updates_done);

    @(updates_done);
    $display("display %0t, %0d", $time, counter);

    @(updates_done);
    $display("display %0t, %0d", $time, counter);

    $finish;
end
```

And prints what I want:

```
monitor 0, 0
display 10, 1
monitor 10, 1
display 30, 2
monitor 30, 2
```

Since a assume this is a common problem when writing test cases in Verilog, my first question is whether there is a better way of doing this? And if not, is my approach correct?

Comment: Your solution should work, but honestly, it is ugly :-). In my experience `#1 $display` is used a lot. Usually clock cycle takes more than1 tick and this is a normal practice. Otherwise, $monitor (or $strobe) can do the work, You can also write a vpi app with a corresponding callback.

Comment: @Serge: I agree it looks ugly, that's the reason I asked this question :-) However, I still think that my problem is valid and it would be better to verify in the same time step as the update happens than in the next one. Would you agree? I guess `$monitor` or `$strobe` could be used together with a script that parses their output. Although this seems cumbersome, it's probably less hacky than my approach :-) If I read the Verilog standard correctly, VPI callbacks cannot be used since their are processed before non-blocking assignments.

Comment: @Job You are not correct about vpi. There are callbacks which are very flexible and can be executed after all evaluations are done.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what `$strobe` is for. Both `$strobe` and `$monitor` wait until the *postponed* event region to render their output. The *postponed* event region is the last point before the simulation time gets updated to the next timestamp.

Comment: That's true but I was only using `$display` as an example. In reality, I want to compare values against expected values and do something with that result. (I updated my question to make this more clear.)

Comment: There's no way to find out what a variables value is going to be until after the variable gets is value. And your workaround with `@(updatedes_done)` would not work if the reg received the same value two clock cycles in a row. You need to step back and explain what you are trying to accomplish and read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: That's the reason I created a new register (`non_blocking_reg`) that's explicitly changed to a different value on every clock cycle. I guess that should work then, no? What I'm trying to accomplish is verifying the value assigned to a register using a non-blocking assignment in the same time step as the assignment. The reason I don't want to postpone that verification to a later time step is that anything could (at least in principle) change in the intermediary time steps. Does that make my goal clear?

Comment: You need to know how the register is sampled at the next stage. This is usually the value it has at the pre-poned region, which is the same as the value it had in the post-poned region of the previous time-step. This is how SystemVerilog assertions work.

Comment: So are you saying that what I want to do is possible in SystemVerilog but not in Verilog? If so, any idea how this problem is usually worked around in a Verilog-only code base? Should I just use the `#1` approach mentioned in one of the comments to my question?

Comment: No. I think your requirements are misguided.You probably should ask a new question showing a realistic example of the situation you seem to think needs to be avoided.